# Laravel Blade: How can I move items that are being pulled from the database into columns?

Tags: php, css, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5.4 and I have a blade file that has many `Form` sections. One of my `Form` sections pulls items from my database and displays the items as checkboxes for my form. I am trying to manipulate the code so that my checkbox items appear in two columns, side-by-side rather than just being displayed in a line one after the other.

Here is the code I am trying to manipulate:

```
<div id="field-container" class="form-group {{ $errors->has('categories') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    {!! Form::label('categories', 'Categories', ['class' => 'req col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="checkbox-group">
    @foreach ($dep_dep_cats['categories'] as $oneCategory)
        {!! Form::checkbox('categories[]',  $oneCategory['id'] ) !!}
        {!! $oneCategory['title'] !!}
    @endforeach
    </div>
    {!! $errors->has('categories') ? '<p class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 text-danger"><strong>' . $errors->first('categories') . '</strong></p>' : '' !!}
</div>
```

I was thinking that I could throw in an `if` statement to align items a certain way based on their id but I was not able to get this to work. I also put a `<div>` around the Blade syntax form items inside of my `@foreach` loop and this lined my items up into one big column, which is closer to what I am going for. How can I split that large column into two smaller columns?

Comment: css `#field-container div.checkbox-group input {width:50%; float:left;}` (you might have to change padding, margins, wisth, box model etc to work with existing styles

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap or another framework?

Comment: Yes, I am using Bootstrap and laravelcollective/html.